# swipeEnabled doesn't work on iOS NativeScript tabs

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to use ns tabs with swipe gesture, and watching its doc, I put swipeEnabled='true' on Tabs tag, but it doesn't work on iOS (working correctly on android).

My code:

```html
<Tabs selectedIndex="0" swipeEnabled="true">
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <TabStrip>
    ...
  </TabStrip>
    ...
</Tabs>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution for this, that also fix RadListView problem with tabs component, just add `animationEnabled="false"` to Tabs tag.